# Android : Instead of next page, it's showing a blank black page (with action bar)

Tags: android

I create login & signup class. user supposed to go to the login page, but if he doesn't have an account he can press the link to sign up page. unfortunately when he click the link, it leads to a blank black page (the action header is there tho). there's no error and as far as I'm concerned my code is correct (well clearly it isnt). here's my code

> > login

```
    package com.spamcity;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class login extends Activity {

    private EditText email;
    private EditText password;
    private Button login;
    private TextView gosignup;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.login);
        setupVariables();

        login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub              
                startActivity(new Intent(login.this, MainActivity.class));
                finish();
            }
        });

        gosignup.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                startActivity(new Intent(login.this, signupActivity.class));                
                finish();
            }
        });
    }

    private void setupVariables(){
        email =  (EditText) findViewById(R.id.logemail);
        password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.logpassword);
        login = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);
        gosignup = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    }
}
```

> > sign up

```
    package com.spamcity;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;

public class signupActivity extends Activity {

    private EditText idNo;
    private EditText fullname;
    private EditText email;
    private EditText password;
    private Button signup;

    public class signupScreen extends Activity {
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.signup);
            setupVariables();
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
            // getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.signup, menu);
            Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSubmitAction);
            button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Welcome", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    startActivity(new Intent(signupActivity.this, MainActivity.class));
                    finish();
                }
            });
            return true;
        }
    }

    private void setupVariables(){
        setIdNo((EditText) findViewById(R.id.signidno));
        setFullName((EditText) findViewById(R.id.signfname));
        setEmail((EditText) findViewById(R.id.signemail));
        setPassword((EditText) findViewById(R.id.signpassword));
    }

    public EditText getIdNo() {
        return idNo;
    }

    public void setIdNo(EditText idNo) {
        this.idNo = idNo;
    }

    public EditText getFullName() {
        return fullname;
    }

    public void setFullName(EditText fullname) {
        this.fullname = fullname;
    }

    public EditText getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(EditText email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public EditText getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(EditText password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public Button getSignup() {
        return signup;
    }

    public void setSignup(Button signup) {
        this.signup = signup;
    }
}
```

> > login xml (link to go to sign up page)

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/btnLogin"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
    android:onClick="onClick"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:text="Sign up if you don&apos;t have an account"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
    android:textSize="12sp" />
```

is there something amiss?

Comment: which activity is blank ? main or signup ?

Comment: The signup activity has an inner class which is the one implementing all the Activity class methods. That's the issue, you'll need to move all your code to the parent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to move your code to the parent class, there's no purpose of having an inner class.
In your case **signupActivity** has no logic, so it wont show anything.

You can fix this by simply removing the inner class.

```
    package com.spamcity;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;

public class signupActivity extends Activity {

    private EditText idNo;
    private EditText fullname;
    private EditText email;
    private EditText password;
    private Button signup;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.signup);
            setupVariables();

            Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSubmitAction);
            button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Welcome", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    startActivity(new Intent(signupActivity.this, MainActivity.class));
                    finish();
                }
            });
        }

    private void setupVariables(){
        setIdNo((EditText) findViewById(R.id.signidno));
        setFullName((EditText) findViewById(R.id.signfname));
        setEmail((EditText) findViewById(R.id.signemail));
        setPassword((EditText) findViewById(R.id.signpassword));
    }

    public EditText getIdNo() {
        return idNo;
    }

    public void setIdNo(EditText idNo) {
        this.idNo = idNo;
    }

    public EditText getFullName() {
        return fullname;
    }

    public void setFullName(EditText fullname) {
        this.fullname = fullname;
    }

    public EditText getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(EditText email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public EditText getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(EditText password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public Button getSignup() {
        return signup;
    }

    public void setSignup(Button signup) {
        this.signup = signup;
    }    
}
```

Let me know if it worked!

Comment: it's a pity there's no thumbs up feature. anyway it's working. thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

So it looks like you have no hints in your edit text. You should try something like this:

```
public void setIdNo(EditText idNo, String idNoHint) {
    this.idNo = idNo;
    this.idNo.setHint(idNoHint);
}
```

Then call it like this:

```
setIdNo((EditText) findViewById(R.id.signidno), "Enter ID Number");
```